# Received " VM error : revert " while calling payable function in remix

Tags: solidity, remix, error, payable

Function prototype is

```
    function pay1(uint xyz) payable{
    require(xyz==msg.value);
}
```

I set (in remix) value to 30 ether and called function with the argument 30.

Answer (score 1):

uint xyz in the function's argument counts in wei.
The msg.value should be 30 wei for that function call to work.
1 ether = 1e18 wei (pentilion)